# drupal 8 accessing input type from label template

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

How do you reference the input type of the respective form input from inside the form element label template (form-element-label.html.twig)?

Answer (score 1):

The element type is not available in that TWIG template. You will have to hook into the form element and pass a variable to the element label hook.

```
/**
 * The contents of $variable['label'] will be passed to the preprocess
 * hook of the element's label.
 */
function theme_preprocess_form_element(array &$variables) {
  $variables['label']['#attributes']["data-element-type"] = $variables['element']['#type'];

}

/** 
 * Now we need to merge the array element we created in the previous hook
 * with the label's attributes.
 */
function theme_preprocess_form_element_label(array &$variables) {
  $variables['attributes'] = array_merge($variables['attributes'], $variables['element']['#attributes']);
}
```

The label will have the following output (I testes on an email element type).

```
<label for="edit-email-addresses" data-element-type="email" class="js-form-required form-required">Email Addresses</label>
```

Don't forget to clear caches ;)